# How do I make has_secure_password (bcrypt hashes) faster in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

Another self-answer for posterity. :)

Creating models with `has_secure_password` (which uses a bcrypt hash) is really slow. `User.create!` takes about 0.3 seconds.

This slows down my test suite. How do I improve performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semyon Perepelitsa graciously [posted](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/285#issuecomment-2482862) the following snippet for test_helper/spec_helper:

```
require "bcrypt"
silence_warnings do
  BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST
end
```

This weakens the hash function, making hash calculation near-instantaneous in test mode - just what we want!

Comment: This is only necessary if you aren't loading the full Rails environment (i.e., isolated tests with ActiveRecord). This got merged in, Rails will do it automatically in the test environment.